# stopwords em python

Tags: python, nltk

Existe alguma forma de fazer `stopword` sem utilizar o `import nlkt`? Estou pesquisando na web mas não tou encontrando outra forma. 
Não consigo instalar o `nltk` no meu Python 3.6 de 64 bits. Sigo todos os passos, mas terminados os passos e já no código o `import` associado (`import nlkt`) não é reconhecido na mesma.

Comment: Não é **NLKT** é **NLTK**. Instalou [NLTK Data](https://www.nltk.org/data.html#interactive-installer) ? Importe: `import nltk` e depois: `nltk.download()`

Comment: Sim, enganei-me. Já fiz isso, mas não deu

Comment: Qual erro é retornado ? Veja se [essa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42313776/) no *SO* pode te ajudar.

Comment: Uma opção é criar a lista com as palavras que você quer remover e criar uma função para substituir por espaço, por exemplo.

Comment: Colega, use uma lista pronta: https://github.com/stopwords-iso/stopwords-pt Neste git o programador já deixou os termos em lista Python, é copiar e usar.

Answer (score 1):

Que tal tentar o seguinte:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk

nltk.download('stopwords')

language = "french"

for word in stopwords.words(language):
    print (word)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]